# LINQ query on dotnet code and how concat will work here

Tags: asp.net, .net, linq

i am not a dot net programmer but need to migrate dotnet code to java .having issue understanding this follwing piece

Lets say specificTermical and ShipTo  have latitutde property with different value  so what happends when we use concat    what will be the final value  eg. 23.10+43.10 or something else

```
List<OrderDispatchItemDTO> locations =(List<OrderDispatchItemDTO>) msg.Details.Select(x => x.SpecificTerminal).Concat(msg.Details.Select(x => x.ShipTo));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line of code that you provide returns a List of `OrderDispatchItemDTO` objects, that contains the values of both the `SpecificTerminal` and `ShipTo` properties of the `Details` objects.

It doesn't make any kind of calculation between the values of `SpecificTerminal` and `ShipTo` properties; it only adds both of them in a common list.

More detailed:

- The `Select` method returns a new `IEnumerable` of the selected objects
- And the `Concat` method concatenates the second collection into the first.

Answer (score 0):

Concat is a string method. When you concatenate "23.10" and "43.10", it gives "23.1043.10". Therefore combining the two strings together.

To do any calculation in c#, you have to convert from strings data types to other mathematical data type that fits the say. 
You may convert those two values to float and add them as shown below:

```
Float sum = Convert.ToFloat(23.10) + Convert.ToFloat(43.10);
```